# maven - updating project POM

Tags: maven

Currently in our team we manually update the POM.xml when we are about to release our package. I came from npm and we would use the npm-bump package to release major/minor/patch versions. I would have thought maven would have an easy way to do this rather than editing the pom.xml file directly.
I took a look at http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html  but this seems to update the dependency and not the current project. Is there another tool to do this ie bump major, minor, or patch with a single command?

Comment: `maven-release-plugin`?

Comment: is their a way to avoid the prompt. the npm bump will just automatically increase it by 1 for which ever grunt command I would use eg release;patch, release:major, or release:minor.

Comment: Just use `mvn -B release:prepare release:perform` and no prompt is there...

Comment: @khmarbaise I go the error `You don't have a SNAPSHOT project in the reactor projects list.` Do I need to have a snapshot in pom.xml? We have our versions like <version>1.9.0</version>

Comment: It also mentioned it needed a developerConnection url so I have it my company's repository however for bumping the version locally why is this needed?